# Clustering data- Poor results, feature extraction

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, signal-processing, unsupervised-learning

I have measured data (vibrations) from a wind turbine running under different operating conditions. My dataset consists of *operating conditions* as well as *measurement features* I have extracted from the measured data.

Dataset shape: `(423, 15)`. Each of the 423 data points represent a measurement on a day, chronologically over 423 days.

[image]

I now want to cluster the data to see if there is any change in the measurements. Specifically, I want to examine if the vibrations change over time (which could indicate a fault in the turbine gearbox).

**What I have currently done:**

1. Scale the data between 0,1 ->
2. Perform PCA (reduce from 15 to 5)
3. Cluster using [db scan](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) since I do not know the number of clusters. I am using this code to find the optimal epsilon (eps) in dbscan:

```py
# optimal Epsilon (distance):
X_pca = principalDf.values
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2)
nbrs = neigh.fit(X_pca)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X_pca)
distances = np.sort(distances, axis=0)
distances = distances[:,1]
plt.plot(distances,color="#0F215A")
plt.grid(True)
```

4. The result so far are not giving any clear indication that the data is changing over time:

[image]

Of course, the case could be that the data is not changing over these data points. Howver, what are some other things I could try? Kind of an open question, but I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with KMeans, if the dataset is not naturally partitioned, you may end up with some very weird results!  As KMeans is unsupervised, you basically dump in all kinds of numeric variables, set the target variable, and let the machine do the lift for you.  Here is a simple example using the canonical Iris dataset.  You can EASILY modify this to fit your specific dataset.  Just change the 'X' variables (all but the target variable) and 'y' variable (just one target variable).  Try that and feedback.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import urllib.request
import random
# seaborn is a layer on top of matplotlib which has additional visualizations -
# just importing it changes the look of the standard matplotlib plots.
# the current version also shows some warnings which we'll disable.
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, 0:4]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target



from sklearn import preprocessing

scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

scaler.fit(X)
X_scaled_array = scaler.transform(X)
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_scaled_array)

X_scaled.sample(5)


# try clustering on the 4d data and see if can reproduce the actual clusters.

# ie imagine we don't have the species labels on this data and wanted to
# divide the flowers into species. could set an arbitrary number of clusters
# and try dividing them up into similar clusters.

# we happen to know there are 3 species, so let's find 3 species and see
# if the predictions for each point matches the label in y.

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

nclusters = 3 # this is the k in kmeans
seed = 0

km = KMeans(n_clusters=nclusters, random_state=seed)
km.fit(X_scaled)

# predict the cluster for each data point
y_cluster_kmeans = km.predict(X_scaled)
y_cluster_kmeans


# use seaborn to make scatter plot showing species for each sample
sns.FacetGrid(data, hue="species", size=4) \
   .map(plt.scatter, "sepal_length", "sepal_width") \
   .add_legend();
```

[image]